# How to Rollback the upgrade farm build version?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, cumulative-update

I installed the CU Updates of the August, then run the command of `Upgrade-SPFarm` command after that my schema version changed, so I can't deploy any solutions in visual studio. I need to rollback the process.

Comment: What you mean by you can't deploy any solutions? Are you able to access the sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no safe rollback path. That is reason we should always backup before applying major changes to the system.

Comment: I have Farm Backup,How long its takes to Restore

Comment: It depends on the size of the backup and number of servers involved in it

Comment: Thank you so much, after up-gradation process I can't deploy any solutions in visual studio,I got this type of errors  Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Comment: did you reset all of your farm servers? did you run the configuration wizard after the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You cant roll back a CU as it upgrade not only the File System on the SharePoint Server as well as upgrade the Databases.

Options, you have to troubleshoot the issue what is casuing the issue.

- Open a Support Ticket with MSFT to solve the problem.
- Examine the Upgrade logs, ULS logs to find any clue.
- I would Run the Configuration Wizard on All Servers
- Still having the issue then try to clear the config cache.

Lastly you can restore from a farm backup, which required a lot of efforts as you have to rebuild your farm.